# capped collection removed document

Tags: mongodb

I want to keep track of the documents removed from capped collection. Is there any way that I can know the when an document has been removed from the capped collection ? I want to maintain a list of the documents removed from the capped collection. Please help me.

Comment: Though it is not possible to recover overwritten documents, Please see if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722833/track-deleted-documents-in-mongo-dbs-capped-collection ?

Comment: I dont want to recover the deleted item. I just want to know the ,say,  _id of the deleted field.

Comment: If the `_id` field was not an `ObjectId`, and is a sequence of numbers, you could identify it easily, it should be in the range: (latest record's `_id` in the collection to `latest _id - collection size`). If it is an `ObjectId`, it is not possible.